How to make text block next to braces pointing to another text all aligned nicely?
I am working on a legal document and I would like to achieve something like the following for the signature block:

I would want the brace to grow with the area of text where the name is as necessary, and the point bit to be aligned with the signature location.
How can I achieve this in LaTeX?

You could use some kind of tabular, like nicematrix and add the } via tikz path decorations. Please show what you already tried.

Nobody prevents you to use a tabular in math mode, where you can then use \left. and \right\}:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
\textbf{Subscribed} for and on behalf of\\
My Company Name\\
acting by Jimmy Head Honcho\\
Might have a long name
\end{tabular}
\right\}$ \lower2ex\rlap{Director}\dotfill\\
at [Place]\\
on [date]
\end{document}


The rather plain TeX-y
\lower2ex\rlap{Director}

might be replaced by the more LaTeX-y
\raisebox{-2ex}{\makebox[0pt][l]{Director}}

